# Would a variable automatically get released from memory if it was never used?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory-management, garbage-collection, v8

Just out of curiosity, if I was to set a variable in JavaScript like this:

```
var name = "Mango";
```

Then **never** reference it would JavaScript *"automatically"* release the variable from memory if it found that it had **never** been used, or would this have been ignored all together and nothing would have happened?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends on how intelligent the runtime is. Since there's a possibility you may be accessing the variable dynamically (`window[userInput]`), this may be very tricky to figure out, but not impossible.

Comment: @deceze My apologies if I was not clear, I'm talking about the Google (Chrome) V8 engine.

Comment: Same thing. Even if it may or may not be able to do that today, that may change tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be deleted, Remember that JavaScript never "looks ahead".
It will never keep track of what will be used in the future.
For all JavaScript knows, you could open a developer's console (assuming this is for a browser) and inject code that does use `mango`.
In general, JavaScript will only delete things that can never be reached.

For example, if you were to then execute:

```
name = "Hi";
```

The string "Mango" would be automatically deleted because there is no reference to it, [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: Yes, this is for a browser also Thank you for the answer & the link, +1.

Answer (score 1):

- If it's a `Local variables`, it automatically gets garbage collected once it goes out of scope.
- If we talk about `Global variables`, global variables are never disposed of by the GC in the sense that a global variable will still exist. Setting it to NULL will allow the memory that it references to be collected.

Comment: Closures can keep local variables alive even after the function that declared them has returned, can they not?

Comment: @meriton I think local variable which are captured by closures gc'ed once the function they are defined in has finished and all functions defined inside their scope are themselves gc'ed.